# Why the author used 'their hand was forced' instead of 'their hands were forced'?

Tags: plural-forms

I am reading an article here.

http://www.davemanuel.com/2008/03/14/why-doesnt-berkshire-hathaway-split-its-stock/

Quote:

> You may say, "Well why did Berkshire Hathaway institute their B shares then?" If it were up to Buffett, the company never would have
>   done this, but **their hand was** forced. Buffett did this move
>   "reluctantly" and only to thwart the creation of unit trusts that
>   would have marketed themselves as Berkshire Hathaway look-alikes.

How can `they` share one hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an idiomatic use of *hand*: to *force X’s hand* means to “compel X to do something” which X would rather not do.

- First, *their* refers not to individuals but to *the company*; this might have been expressed just as correctly with *its*. It is the company’s hand which was forced, not the individual hands of individual stockholders.
- Second, there are no actual hands involved, only a single metaphorical ‘hand’, a collective willingness to act.

Answer (score 1):

"Hand" in this context, refers to cards that you hold in "hand," in a game.

The meaning of the quote was not that Berkshire's "hand(s)" was forced in any literal sense, but the company was forced to play the "game" in a certain way, by issuing B shares. Or else the unit trusts would have done so (in a round about way).

Comment: I don't think the term relates to cards, but rather to the fact that many actions are controlled by the use of one hand.

Comment: @supercat: That's true more "blue collar workers." But most executives are white collar workers.

Comment: How many hands would be required to sign a document?